# Error on workbench install

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to install mysql workbench in ubuntu 16.04. I just installed the OS.

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb
[sudo] password for lucas: 
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 179177 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.3.9-1ubuntu16.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libgeos-c1v5 (>= 3.4.2); however:
  Package libgeos-c1v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libhdf4-0-alt; however:
  Package libhdf4-0-alt is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libjasper1; however:
  Package libjasper1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libmysqlclient20 (>= 5.7.11); however:
  Package libmysqlclient20 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libnetcdf11 (>= 4.0.1); however:
  Package libnetcdf11 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7); however:
  Package libpcrecpp0v5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpq5; however:
  Package libpq5 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libxerces-c3.1; however:
  Package libxerces-c3.1 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libzip4 (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libzip4 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on python-paramiko (>= 1.15.1); however:
  Package python-paramiko is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.04.20170406-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: So what's your question exactly? `dpkg -i` does not attempt to resolve dependencies, if you want an installer that does so use `gdebi` instead - or install the provided version of `mysql-workbench` from the repository using `apt`

Comment: I want one way to install the workbench. Neither `dpkg` or `gdebi` worked for me.

Comment: I've updated my answer please check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because of that `mysql-workbench-community` package dependencies is not be installed before.

So try to install them before installing `mysql-workbench-community` package.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgeos-c1v5 libhdf4-0-alt libjasper1 libmysqlclient20 libnetcdf11 libpcrecpp0v5 libpng12-0 libpq5 libxerces-c3.1 libzip4 python-paramiko python-crypto
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb
```

Or as an **alternative** and **best way** automate this installation process by `gdebi` :

```
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb
```

**UPDATE**: Both [libjasper1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjasper1) and [libpng12-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0) packages are available in Xenial repositories.

So for install them your `xenial-security main` and `xenial main` repositories should be enabled. Then try `sudo apt update`. Now you can install them.

Also as a second option you can download and install these packages manually:

`libjasper1` for Xenial 64 bit: [download](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jasper/libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)

`libpng12-0` for Xenial 64 bit: [downlaod](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

Then install them with this command:

```
sudo gdebi libjasper1_1.900.1-debian1-2.4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: None of the options worked. - 1: E: Package 'libjasper1' has no installation candidate E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate 2: Dependency is not satisfiable: libjasper1

Comment: @LucasThibauPaulino Both `libjasper1` and `libpng12-0` are available in Xenial repositories https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0 // https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libjasper1 // Please check your repoes | you can also download and install these packages manually

Comment: Thanks, the first three statements worked for me! However, I had changed my server from main to United States

Answer (score 0):

For me permissions was missing Try Giving permissions to the app in Ubuntu

```
1. Go To Ubuntu Store >> App
2. Give Read, Write Permissions for Workbench in Ubuntu Store
```

Have a look,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxMOm.png